# Login with multiple users in same test using json

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to test the login using multiple users in a single test rather than logging in with one then logging out and then moving to a duplicate test and using different users.

This is the JSON i will be using to fetch data

```
[
    {
      "id": "standard User",
      "username": "standard_user",
      "password": "secret_sauce"
    },
    {
      "id": "locked out user",
      "username": "locked_out_user",
      "isComplete": "secret_sauce"
    },
    {
      "id": "Problem user",
      "username": "problem_user",
      "password": "secret_sauce"
    },
    {
      "id": "perfromance glitch user",
      "username": "performance_glitch_user",
      "password": "secret_sauce"
    },
    {
        "id": "Invalid User",
        "username": "perform",
        "password": "secret12"
      }
]
```

And below is the script

```
it('Login with multple users', () => {
        
        //Logging in with the first User.
        cy.visit('/')
        cy.get('[data-test="username"]').type(user[0].username)
        cy.get('[data-test="password"]').type(user[0].password)
        cy.get('[data-test="login-button"]').click()
        cy.url('https://www.saucedemo.com/inventory.html')
        // Logging in with the second User.
        cy.visit('/')
        cy.get('[data-test="username"]').type(user[1].username)
        cy.get('[data-test="password"]').type(user[1].password)
        cy.get('[data-test="login-button"]').click()
        cy.get('[data-test="error"]').should('have.text', 'Epic sadface: Sorry, this user has been locked out.')
    });
    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
it('Login with multiple users', () => {
  cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/users.json').then((users) => {
    users.forEach((user) => {
      cy.visit('/')
      cy.get('[data-test="username"]').type(user.username)
      cy.get('[data-test="password"]').type(user.password)
      cy.get('[data-test="login-button"]').click()
      cy.url('https://www.saucedemo.com/inventory.html')
      cy.get('[data-test="error"]').should(
        'have.text',
        'Epic sadface: Sorry, this user has been locked out.'
      )
    })
  })
})
```

Also in your JSON, in the second entry there is no `password` field instead there is `isComplete`.

Comment: Thanks this works, I am able to log in multiple times but out of 4 credentials, three are supposed to be an error. How I can work around that? For example, the above assertion is for the second set of credentials but its looks for it when it logs in the first time and cant find it.

Comment: If I understood correctly, You can add another field for error messages in the JSON for validating different error messages. Also I would suggest you to write a new question if this doesn't resolve your query.

Comment: for example

User 1 I need to verify a certain URL.
User 2 I need to verify type 1 error message.
User 3 I need to verify type 2 error message.
User 4 I need to verify type 3 error message.

When the test runs with first user its looking for type 1 error. How i like map type 1 error when test runs second time?

Comment: I would suggest you open a new question for this as this goes beyond the scope of the current question.

Comment: Sure, I was thinking the same.